# Перевернуть список

Tags: python

не подскажете почему пример из [документации](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) не работает?

```
a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
print(a.reverse(), end='\n\n\n')

print(a)
```

у меня на экране результат такой:

> None
>
> [1234.5, 1, 333, 333, 66.25]

версия python 3.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что метод reverse переворачивает список, но ничего не возвращает.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
```

если вы хотите чтобы функция возвращал перевернутый список не изменяя его - используйте функцию reversed (будьте внимательны, функция вернет итератор!)

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(reversed(a))
[3, 2, 1]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно копировать список целиком `::` и итерировать в обратном порядке - к пр. так:

```
for i in a[::-1]: print i,"\n"
```

У print неявная конкатенация строк через запятую - туда можно и \n\n впихать, на версии 3 должно быть также.

В принципе, лучший ответ уже был дан - метод reversed (в противовес reverse()):

```
for i in reversed(a): print i
```

Также, если я такой уж многословный, возможно вам нужна разновидность списка (stack - first in last out):

```
a = [66.25]
a.append(333)
a.append(333)
a.pop()
333
a.pop()
333
a.pop()
66.25
```

Answer (score 2):

```
buff = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
buff0 = buff[::-1] # переворачиваем список вобратном порядке
print(buff0) # [10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

А где пример из документации не работает? Все работает. Реверс получился же. Реверс != сортировка.

Comment: что-то я заглючил